# Canonical URL Issue

Tags: expressionengine

I am experiencing an issue with setting canonical urls for my website. Moz crawler shows that each page is missing a canonical and when I inspect the page, the canonical is shown as follow:

```
<link rel=""canonical"" href=""https://website.com/"">
```

This goes for each webpage.

The website was built by a third party and the wait time for corrections is rather long. I've checked the CMS and the repository for errors, but nothing looks out of the ordinary. Any ideas?

edit: I should mention that I am aware of the extra quotes, but am unable to identify the error. Repository lists the following:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{site_url}/{segment_1}/{segment_2}" />
```

Comment: It looks like you have two sets of quotes in each prop. Have you tried just doing <link rel="canonical" href="https://website.com/">?

Comment: This is what I've got right now:  

<link rel="canonical" href="{site_url}/{segment_1}/{segment_2}" />

Comment: Are you add this tag in head tag?

Comment: Can you share the website URL which have the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To be valid it should look like so:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://website.com" />
```

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned I understood that. My issues is that I can't figure out where the issue lies. Or what is producing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the segments aren't set properly. Maybe they are set with something like freebie?
Anyway, the way it's set up now you will get some unwanted slashes if there are no url segments.. Maybe better to change this to something like `<link rel="canonical" href="{site_url}/{if segment_1}{segment_1}/{/if}{if segment_2}{segment_2}/{/if}" />`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Gave it a shot but issue persists.

Comment: do any segments render in the templates? if you are on the mysite.com/contact page for instance, does {segment_1} render "contact" in the template?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have expected to find a double set of quotes somewhere within the repository, but no such luck.